# What to install for glib-networking dev package

Tags: ubuntu, glibc, glib

What package I need to install in order to resolve this error:

```
configure: error: libsoup requires glib-networking for TLS support.
```

I have tried:

```
sudo apt-get install glib-networking-dbg
sudo apt-get install glib-networking-dev
sudo apt-get install libglib-networking-dev
```

but none of them works.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If g_tls_backend_supports_tls() returns false for glib/gio it means you have no gio module installed that provides tls support.

If this exists `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiognutls.so` it will provide the the gio module for tls, it comes from `glib-networking`, which is installed. Not sure if that the default place on x86_64 that gets searched for that shared object.

You could have to set GIO_MODULE_DIR in your env. Setting GIO_MODULE_DIR gets me passed the error.

```
GIO_MODULE_DIR=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no glib-networking dev package. The package only contains dynamic modules. So installing `glib-networking` should work.

PS. If you don't know the name of a dev package, as I often don't, you can search on http://packages.ubuntu.com.

Comment: Thanks. But i have install glib-networking, but it still said it can't find it. "$ sudo apt-get install glib-networking", 'glib-networking is already the newest version.'

Comment: Then take a look at [libsoup's configure.ac](http://git.gnome.org/browse/libsoup/tree/configure.ac) to see what it is looking for - it looks like it is trying to compile a program that calls `g_tls_backend_supports_tls()`. Can you try to compile that program yourself?